# Not clear on this jQuery syntax: return !$()

Tags: boolean-logic, logical-operators, jquery

I saw this code and I'm not clear what the '`!`' does in this line of jQuery code on the return on the jQuery object:

```
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1');
});
```

**EDIT**

What is a good case to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It converts the result of `$('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1')` to a boolean, and negates it.

However, as the result of `appendTo` is always a jQuery object, and an object (jQuery or not) is always truthy, the result of `!$('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1')` is **always** false.

So what we have is effectively:

```
$('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1');

    return false;
});
```

Returning `false` in a jQuery event handler will stop the default event action occuring (e.g. the submission of a form/ navigation of a hyperlink) *and* stop the event propagating any further up the DOM tree.

So what we have is effectively:

```
$('#remove').click(function(e) {
    $('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Using `return false` instead of `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` is OK, but using the `return !$(..)` as a shortcut for the first example is ridiculous, and there is ***no*** need to do it.

#### Just to reiterate my point, the most important thing to note here is that there is never, ever a good reason/ case to do this.

Links:

1. [Docs for `bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (alias for `click()`)
2. [Docs for `preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
3. [Docs for `stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: how do they convert it, as it returns a jQuery object, usually a collection of DOM elements ? // thanks for the edit

Comment: @Matt - Thanks.  I should have asked the follow up question, why would you want to do this?

Comment: They were probably trying to negate the standard browser action. Returning `false` in jQuery is the wrong way to do it though; instead, you should use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). (Edit: Matt beat me to it with his edit :)).

Comment: @Mark: I hope my edit has answered your question. (Damn StackOverflow not letting you "@" more than one user per comment).